# Using Braintree and Stripe in Android app

Tags: android, stripe-payments, braintree

I have developped an Android app and the only thing left is to implement a payment solution to sell goods. 
I have been searching for a while and found Stripe and Braintree. It seems that they are pretty much the same in many aspects.
However, I was wondering which one is the best to use for a user of my app: for instance, does Stripe require that each user has a Stripe account? What are the performances and the number of forms to fill-in for a user?
To sum up, which one is the more user-friendly?

Comment: Hey, Braintree dev here. I second what Matthew Arkin said below, and don't hesitate to reach out to our support team if you need help with the integration! -Chrissie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither requires the customer have an account with their solution. For the most part the ease of use from the customer perspective come from how you design the app / form.

Braintree offers a pre-built design (Drop In) for Android, Stripe's built in offering (Checkout) is only offered on iOS.

Both allow you to use your own form to collect CC info.

Both support Apple Pay / Android Pay (when it comes out).

Braintree supports Paypal and Venmo.

To the end user in most cases they just enter their card number, expiration, cvc code, its just one form, how simple you make it is up to you.